# TypeInitializationException using NCrawler; missing Autofac method

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler, console-application, autofac

I was doing some tests with NCrawler and got this weird Exception:

> The type initializer for 'NCrawler.NCrawlerModule' threw an exception.
>   The inner Exception is: Method not found: 'Void
>   Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule(Autofac.ContainerBuilder,
>   Autofac.Core.IModule)'.

The exception occurs in the Crawlers constructor.

Here is my code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Crawler c = new Crawler(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"), new HtmlDocumentProcessor(), new TestStep()))
        {
            c.MaximumThreadCount = 3;
            c.MaximumCrawlDepth = 2;
            c.ExcludeFilter = new[] { new RegexFilter(
            new Regex(@"(\.jpg|\.css|\.js|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.png|\.ico)",
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) };
            c.Crawl();
        }
    }
```

And here is the TestStep class:

```
public class TestStep : IPipelineStep
{
    public void Process(Crawler crawler, PropertyBag propertyBag)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(propertyBag.Step.Uri.ToString());
    }
}
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Autofac Using NuGet but it doesn't worked. 
The weird thing is that the version on `packages.config` is 3.5.2 but on `app.config` it seems to try to bind it to 3.5.0
Here is the AutoFac in packages.config:

```
 <package id="Autofac" version="3.5.2" targetFramework="net452" />
```

and in app.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeInitializationException` means the static constructor on something failed. In this case, the static constructor on `NCrawlerModule` failed. That's the place to start looking.

The whole of the NCrawler project looks pretty messed up.

- It started on CodePlex. [Here's the CodePlex version of `NCrawlerModule`](https://ncrawler.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Net 4.0/NCrawler/NCrawlerModule.cs). The original code [was bound to Autofac 2.4.5](https://ncrawler.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Net 4.0/NCrawler/NCrawler.csproj)
- The latest version of the project code [is actually on GitHub](https://github.com/esbencarlsen/NCrawler) and in the latest `master` branch the `NCrawlerModule` doesn't exist, or at least I can't find it.
- The version of [NCrawler on NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NCrawler/) isn't actually the latest code - it's a fork [someone ported to GitHub](https://github.com/kant2002/NCrawler). You can see that by clicking on the "Project Site" link from NuGet.
- The NuGet package on NuGet [says it will work with Autofac 3.1.5+](https://github.com/kant2002/ncrawler/blob/a82a531741a4cef737d20e56fea895a9075fd068/NuGet/NCrawler/ncrawler.nuspec#L14) but the [project itself is bound to Autofac 3.5.2](https://github.com/kant2002/ncrawler/blob/a82a531741a4cef737d20e56fea895a9075fd068/NuGet/NCrawler/ncrawler.nuspec#L14).

The point of all this is that you may have to do a little spelunking with [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or your favorite decompiler right on the NCrawler assemblies *you're using* to see what you have in there. It's not obvious from the question or from all the copies and inconsistencies out there.

Anyway, looking at [the static constructor on `NCrawlerModule`](https://github.com/kant2002/ncrawler/blob/a82a531741a4cef737d20e56fea895a9075fd068/Net%204.0/NCrawler/NCrawlerModule.cs#L19) you see it is, in fact, [eventually trying to call a `RegisterModule()` extension method](https://github.com/kant2002/ncrawler/blob/a82a531741a4cef737d20e56fea895a9075fd068/Net%204.0/NCrawler/NCrawlerModule.cs#L72).

Now, [looking at `Autofac.RegistrationExtensions` in Autofac 3.5.2](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/v3.5.2/Core/Source/Autofac/RegistrationExtensions.cs), sure enough, **there is no `RegisterModule` method**. In 3.5.2, that method [is in a `ModuleRegistrationExtensions` class](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/v3.5.2/Core/Source/Autofac/ModuleRegistrationExtensions.cs#L263), which is why you're seeing the exception: **NCrawler is looking in the wrong place.**

What that boils down to is that **you probably have a version of NCrawler compiled against Autofac 2.4.5 and you're trying to use Autofac 3.x with it**. Or, at the very least, you have NCrawler and you're trying to use *some version* of Autofac with which that version of NCrawler is incompatible.

You probably could have avoided the issue if the NuGet package properly specified which versions it worked with, but, again, it seems like there's some confusion with that project.

And, again, you can verify all this by looking at the decompiled version of your NCrawler assembly and checking what it references. I'm guessing it's a pretty old version of Autofac.

**You have two options to solve the problem.**

- Get a new version of NCrawler that is compiled against a more recent Autofac. You can either convince those project maintainers to update their package or you can fork and do it yourself.
- You can figure out which old version of Autofac that your NCrawler is using and roll your whole app back to the old Autofac. This sounds painful to me since you'll be stuck back in time. I, personally, prefer to try to get things to move forward.

Also, hopefully, now you know what to start looking at when you see these exceptions in the future: start with the static constructor and don't be afraid to start spelunking in third-party source.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I suspected that the version of Autofac was the problem. I'm going to try and get a new version of NCrawler.